# Understanding jQueryUI events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to better understand events for jQueryUI plugins such as http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/.

For instance, I have the select( event, ui ) event.  According to the documentation, it appears that the two bits of code are identical.  Correct?

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  select: function( event, ui ) {}
});

( ".selector" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

Okay, I guess both are attaching an event handler function for the "autocompleteselect" event to the selected element.  The documentation also shows the "type" for the "select" event as "autocompleteselect".  But I thought the event name was "select".  Is it "select" or "autocompleteselect"?  Note that I first tried to go through the jQueryUI source code, but but the string "autocompleteselect" is never used.  Where is "autocompleteselect" defined?

My next source of confusion is when I put code inside the anonymous function associated with the event.  Does this code always execute first, and then any additional default plugin code associated with the even execute?  Will `event.preventDefault();` also prevent the default behavior?

Comment: The event itself is named "autocompleteselect" - it's what you're passing to `on`. The items you pass to the constructor of the Autocomplete plugin are used to initialize things. The `select` option is the way to specify what to do on the `autocompleteselect` event that the Autocomplete plugin manually fires. Using `on` later is a way to bind a handler to that event, dynamically.

Comment: Ah, I guess it makes sense that "select" is an option which specifies the function, not an event.  Thanks

Comment: Yeah, event names are unrelated to widget options, yet there is a convention (as pointed out in the answers by Arun P Johny). Just because the option is called `select` doesn't mean that's the name of the event or anything related. With the `select` option, the event that the widget triggers could be called `itemchange`...and the event you'd handle would be `autocompleteitemchange`. But now we know, things are matching up more (probably because it makes sense and it's easier). The option is called `select`, the event fired is `select` (internally), and you listen for `autocompleteselect`.

Comment: It's not true that the option and event type are unrelated. The event type is built from the option name, so they're very much related. You will never find an event type that does not end with the option name. The prefix is currently customizable, but that will likely go away in the future and will be forced to the widget name (plus a colon).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

These two things are not really identical. They just do the same thing ;-) Well, almost.

First, I need to explain a bit of theory:
In general, when dealing with "asynchronous" code, you have two options: callbacks and event listeners. **Callback** is a function, invoked by system, after some other action is finished. Typically you configure object or run a function and "prime" the callback to kick on when comething happens. **Event listener** is invoked by the system when an event occurs. Typically, you bind a bunch of event listeners to the event and other parts of code may trigger the event, triggering all the listener functions.

When you are not used to both events and callback, you may not see the difference. Just know that using callbacks leads to compact "spaghetti" like code, on the other hand using listeners leads to flexible but hard to read code. I believe the best approach is to combine both to get most readable code possible.

In your particular case, "select" is a property of the configuration object, that specifies a callback function.

"autocompleteselect" is a name of the event - you can add listeners to that event

```
$('.selector').on('autocompleteselect', doSomething);
```

or trigger the event yourself

```
$('.selector').trigger('autocompleteselect');
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a functionality added by the widget factory. When an event is fired using [_trigger](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_trigger) it will actually fire an event with type `widget name + type`.

Ex: If you are creating an widget with name `mywidget` and firing an event with in the widget like `this._trigger('select')` the actual event fired will be `mywidgetselect`.

so if you look at the `autocomplete` source code you can find that `this._trigger( "select", ...)` is used there.

You can also refer [this blog](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/tips-for-developing-jquery-ui-widgets/) for some more details

Comment: Thanks.  Reviewing as we speak.